# CodePipeline error: class java.lang.Boolean can not be converted to an String

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline that will use AWS SAM template to create resources. I have codecommit as source, codebuild as build and cloudformation as deploy and when I enter all the parameters and hit create pipeline I get this error.

Comment: Can you include the relevant code please?

Comment: it's a bug on the console